# Edit File on USB :: umount Target is busy

Tags: tramp, files

If I insert a USB drive and edit a file on it, then kill the buffer, I have to wait atleast five minutes before I'm able to umount the drive

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sdl1
umount: /mnt/sdl1: target is busy.
```

If I kill emacs itself, then I can umount immediately, so it seems Emacs wants to hold on to the file for a while..

Any way to not have it do that?;)

EDIT: I open the file with sudo privileges.

```
quasar in ﰬ2 ~ 2s
BASHY $ sudo umount /dev/sdl1
umount: /mnt/sdl1: target is busy.
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $ sudo lsof /dev/sdl1
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sh      3467167 root  cwd    DIR  8,177     4096    1 /mnt/sdl1
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $ ps -ef|grep -i 3467167
root     3467167 3467166  0 21:30 pts/44   00:00:00 /bin/sh -i
b0ef     3467859 3433179  0 21:31 pts/11   00:00:00 grep -i 3467167
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $ ps -ef|grep -i 3467166
root     3467166 3294614  0 21:30 pts/44   00:00:00 sudo -u root -s -H /bin/sh -i
root     3467167 3467166  0 21:30 pts/44   00:00:00 /bin/sh -i
b0ef     3468139 3433179  0 21:31 pts/11   00:00:00 grep -i 3467166
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $ ps -ef|grep -i 3294614
b0ef     3294614 3294606  0 14:28 ?        00:00:42 emacs
root     3467166 3294614  0 21:30 pts/44   00:00:00 sudo -u root -s -H /bin/sh -i
b0ef     3468305 3433179  0 21:32 pts/11   00:00:00 grep -i 3294614
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
```

EDIT 2: This is how the file is opened with sudo:

```
(defun er-sudo-edit (&optional arg)
  "Edit currently visited file as root.

With a prefix ARG prompt for a file to visit.
Will also prompt for a file to visit if current
buffer is not visiting a file."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (or arg (not buffer-file-name))
      (find-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:"
                         (ido-read-file-name "Find file(as root): ")))
    (find-alternate-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" buffer-file-name))))

(define-key my-mode-map (kbd "C-M-b g") #'er-sudo-edit)
```

EDIT 3:
I'm now using the package sudo-edit, but I'm still getting a busy signal.

```
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $ sudo umount /dev/sdl1
umount: /mnt/sdl1: target is busy.
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $ sudo lsof /dev/sdl1
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuseblk file system /mnt/sdh1
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sh      538093 root  cwd    DIR  8,177     4096    1 /mnt/sdl1
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $ ps -ef|grep -i 538093
root      538093  538092  0 21:45 pts/49   00:00:00 /bin/sh -i
b0ef      539076 3433179  0 21:46 pts/11   00:00:00 grep -i 538093
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $ ps -ef|grep -i 538092
root      538092 3771955  0 21:45 pts/49   00:00:00 sudo -u root -s -H /bin/sh -i
root      538093  538092  0 21:45 pts/49   00:00:00 /bin/sh -i
b0ef      539119 3433179  0 21:46 pts/11   00:00:00 grep -i 538092
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $ ps -ef|grep -i 3771955
b0ef      318886 3771955  0 13:22 ?        00:00:00 /nix/store/j80wcbm6bb1nsqsgmniq43rg980p27q9-bash-5.2-p15/bin/bash /run/current-system/sw/bin/OmniSharp -lsp
root      538092 3771955  0 21:45 pts/49   00:00:00 sudo -u root -s -H /bin/sh -i
b0ef      539332 3433179  0 21:46 pts/11   00:00:00 grep -i 3771955
b0ef     3771955 3771944  0 May04 ?        00:09:22 emacs
b0ef     3772185 3771955  0 May04 ?        00:00:00 /nix/store/j80wcbm6bb1nsqsgmniq43rg980p27q9-bash-5.2-p15/bin/bash /run/current-system/sw/bin/OmniSharp -lsp
quasar in ﰬ2 ~
BASHY $
```

EDIT 4: Ok, sudo-edit is not sudoedit from Tramp;) I will try that.

Comment: probably not emacs, but a sub-process. what type of file are you editing? what does `lsof` about it?

Comment: Looks as if the `sh` process (pid: 3467167) has `/mnt/sdl1` as its current working directory, which is enough to keep it busy. `cd` to some other directory in that shell, or `kill -HUP 3467167` to terminate the shell and then try unmounting again.

Comment: , but there is no active shell that has pwd of /mnt/sdl1; this is spawned from emacs. I'm sure a kill will let me umount, but why is it holding it in the first place? Also, if I wait five minutes, I'm able to umount

Comment: You have to find out who did the `sudo ...` that started 3467166 (which spawned the `sh` with pid 3467167). If you didn't do that, then who did? The `lsof` output shows that the `cwd` of pid 3467167 is on /dev/sdl1.

Comment: Maybe there is a daemon or cron job that mounts the USB file system periodically and  unmounts it after five minutes of inactivity. Perhaps `automount` or similar? This is most probably a problem outside Emacs, so look at the rest of your system.

Comment: OK, so you are opening files using `sudo` through `tramp`. The tramp manual says: `‘sudo’

     Similar to ‘su’ method, ‘sudo’ uses ‘sudo’.  ‘sudo’ must have
     sufficient rights to start a shell.

     For security reasons, a ‘sudo’ connection is disabled after a
     predefined timeout (5 minutes by default).  This can be changed,
     see *note Predefined connection information::.
` which explains the 5 minute delay. Try killing the `tramp/sudo` buffers if you want the unmount to happen sooner.

Answer (score 1):

`sudoedit` might a good choice, but it is a little bit slow. If you are using Tramp's `sudo`, you could kill the internal process by one of the commands `tramp-cleanup-connection`, `tramp-cleanup-this-connection` or friends.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the `sudoedit` method that `tramp` implements, instead of using the `sudo` method in `er-sudo-edit` (btw, where did that function come from?)

The manual says:

> ## 3.5 Using ‘sudoedit’
>
> The ‘sudoedit’ method is similar to the ‘sudo’ method.  However, it is a
> different implementation: it does not keep an open session running in
> the background.  This is for security reasons; on the backside this
> method has worse performance than the ‘sudo’ method, it is restricted to
> ‘localhost’ only, and it does not support external processes.

So there is no `sh` process to keep the mount point busy and you should be able to unmount without having to wait, or kill the `tramp/sudo` session buffers.